# Change roles permission

Tags: laravel, authentication, user-controls, laravel-5, user-roles

I'm trying to make it some the admin can decide which role can do what, from the frontend easily, but I'm a bit stuck. I've tried a couple of different things, but none of them worked so far.

I've tried this so far:

```
@foreach($role as $role) 
    {!! Form::model($permission, [
        'method' => 'PATCH',
        'url'    => 'settings/permissionsUpdate',
    ]) !!}

    <br />
    {{$role->name}}
    <br />

    <input type="hidden" name="role_id" value="{{ $role->id }}" />

    @foreach($permission as $perm)
        <select name="permissions[ {{ $perm->id }} ]">
            <option value="1">Allowed</option>
            <option value="0">Not Allowed</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        {{$perm->name}}
        <br />
    @endforeach

    {!! Form::submit('Save Settings', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}

@endforeach
```

Ths is my database

```
Permission_role
    * id
    * Role_id
    * Permmission_id

Permission
    * id
    * Name
    * Slug
    * Description

Roles
    * id
    * Name
    * Slug
    * Description

Role_user
    * id
    * role_id
    * user_id
```

And the controller

```
public function permissionsUpdate(Request $request)
{
    $allowed_permissions = [];

    foreach($request->input('permissions') as $permission) {
        if ($permission == 1) {
            $allowed_permissions[] = $permission;
        }

        $role = Role::find($request->input('role_id'));
        $role->permissions()->sync($allowed_permissions); //Currently gives error
        $role->save();
    }
}
```

Im getting the error
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::syncPermission().

Models
Role:

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('permissions');
}
```

Permission

```
public function PermissionsRole()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\PermissionRole', 'role_id', 'id');
}
```

But i have to admit i'm abit on lost ground. I need to attach and deatach the permissions to the roles, and can't reallt figure out how to do this

I still can't seem to figure this out, i tried not sure how i'm gonna attach or deattach permissons to users.

UPDATE:

i've tried this so far, and im getting close but still a few problems.

I had the problem of my Model being wrong, it tried to finde table role_role so i changed it to

```
public function permissions()
{ 
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\permission'); (Had to make a new model called permisson, because when i used permissions it looked for role_permissions and it is called role_permission, but the table alone is called permissions, bit confsuing there)
}
```

And that almost made it work, but It only changes the first value(1) Even if all are on allowed it only attaches the permissons_id equal to 1 and then role id equal to the correct role_id, if i dd the Request it seems to get all the correct data with permission_id = 1, 2 ,3 ,4 etc, but it goes wrong somewhere after that.  Also the view still dosen't show which is allowed or not from start. Coulndt get it to work, i tried something like:

```
<option value="1" {{ @ifUserCan($perm->slug)  ? 'selected="selected"' : null }} >Allowed</option>
<option value="0" {{ @ifUserCan($perm->slug) ? null : 'selected="selected"' @endif }}>Not Allowed</option>
```

But yeah you can't do that.

Comment: Please post your models.

Comment: Of course my bad, just added them.

Comment: Your relations are wrong. It should be `belongsToMany` instead of `hasMany`. change it and let me know. For more information your `permission_role` table is a pivot and you don't need a separate model to handle it. Refer to https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: I got an error saying permissions wasen't found but i figured that was because $role->permissions()->sync($allowed_permissions); actully had to be $role->permissionsRole->sync($allowed_permissions); or am i wrong? But i changed it and im getting the error FatalErrorException in SettingsController.php line 81:
Call to a member function sync() on null

Comment: Does `permissions` and `roles` table have an `id` attribute? If yes please edit your post. If no add them to your tables.
Remove `PermissionRole` model since it's unnecessary. Update your `Permission` and `Role` model and add the following:
In `Permission` model add:
`public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Permission');
}`
In `Role` model add:
`public function persmissions(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Role');
}`
Then you're good with `$role->permissions()->synch($array_of_ids)`.

Comment: I'm getting the `error SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel.role_role' doesn't exist (SQL: select `role_id` from `role_role` where `role_id` = 1)` not sure why it looks for role_role